# xml2 extract URL from .atomsvc file

Tags: r, xml2

I'm working to scrape a public data source that relies on .atomsvc files to allow users to setup a data feed in Excel. I've built a really fragile parser in R using the XML library to extract the URL. I was wondering how this could be done in xml2 (preferably in a more succinct and elegant way)

Here is how I'm doing it using the XML library

```
# Crystal Reports Parser Sample
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

# Get the .atomsvc file from the Export to Data Feed Option on the PA DEP website
pa_string <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"><workspace><atom:title>Oil_Gas_Well_Production</atom:title><collection href="http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer?%2FOil_Gas%2FOil_Gas_Well_Production&amp;P_PERIOD_ID=198&amp;P_COUNTY%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_CLIENT%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PERMIT_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_OGO_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PRODUCING%3Aisnull=True&amp;rs%3AParameterLanguage=&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3ADataFeed=xAx0x2"><atom:title>Tablix1</atom:title></collection></workspace></service>'

pa_list <- pa_string %>% xmlParse() %>% xmlToList()
# Extract the URL
URL <- URLdecode(pa_list$workspace$collection$.attrs)
```

Here is as far as I've gotten with the xml2 version

```
# Crystal Reports xml2 Parser
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

# Get the .atomsvc file from the Export to Data Feed Option on the PA DEP website
pa_string <- '<service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"><workspace><atom:title>Oil_Gas_Well_Production</atom:title><collection href="http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer?%2FOil_Gas%2FOil_Gas_Well_Production&amp;P_PERIOD_ID=198&amp;P_COUNTY%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_CLIENT%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PERMIT_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_OGO_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PRODUCING%3Aisnull=True&amp;rs%3AParameterLanguage=&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3ADataFeed=xAx0x2"><atom:title>Tablix1</atom:title></collection></workspace></service>'

pa_list <- pa_string %>% read_xml() %>% as_list()
```

I don't know how to extract the URL from here, or if this is even the right way to think about how to think about this. Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, by extracting the attribute from the specified node:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

pa_string <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"><workspace><atom:title>Oil_Gas_Well_Production</atom:title><collection href="http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer?%2FOil_Gas%2FOil_Gas_Well_Production&amp;P_PERIOD_ID=198&amp;P_COUNTY%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_CLIENT%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PERMIT_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_OGO_NUM%3Aisnull=True&amp;P_PRODUCING%3Aisnull=True&amp;rs%3AParameterLanguage=&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=ATOM&amp;rc%3ADataFeed=xAx0x2"><atom:title>Tablix1</atom:title></collection></workspace></service>'

 pa_string %>% 
  read_xml() %>% 
  xml_find_all("//*[name()='collection']")%>%
  xml_attr("href") 
#output
[1] "http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer?%2FOil_Gas%2FOil_Gas_Well_Production&P_PERIOD_ID=198&P_COUNTY%3Aisnull=True&P_CLIENT%3Aisnull=True&P_PERMIT_NUM%3Aisnull=True&P_OGO_NUM%3Aisnull=True&P_PRODUCING%3Aisnull=True&rs%3AParameterLanguage=&rs%3ACommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=ATOM&rc%3ADataFeed=xAx0x2"

xpath:

#// - Recursive descent; searches for the specified element at any depth. 
#* -  Matches any element node
#[ ] - Applies a filter pattern.
#name()='collection' - self explanatory
```

Even shorter:

```
pa_string %>% 
  read_xml() %>% 
  xml_find_all("//@href") #select all attributes with name `href`
```

since only one element with atribute, one can also do:

```
pa_string %>% 
  read_xml() %>% 
  xml_find_all("//@*") #Matches any attribute node
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The proper use of xml_find_all is new to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Added explanation for the xpath. It can be really powerful to parse large xml. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp